# Kernel extension not removed from /Library/StagedExtension in High Sierra OSX

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, macos-high-sierra

After uninstalling the kernel extension, the kext still remains in /Library/StagedExtension. Is this an bug from Apple in latest High Sierra OSX 10.13 Beta 6? What could be the reason and solution

Comment: When SIP is enabled, we cannot manually delete kext

Answer (score 0):

This was the bug from Apple, they fixed in 10.13.4